# 32-bit and 64-bit error in building R package which calls Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, package

I'm trying to build an R package which calls Fortran code in Windows system. R BUILD works well but I got some error in R CHECK or R INSTALL.

To compile the Fortran code to get a dll file in Windows system, I have to specify x64 (64 bit) or i386 (32-bit). But when I used dll file compiled by x64 in R CHECK, I will get the error:

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/catch.Rcheck/catch/libs/i386/tensor.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Similarly, if I used the dll file compiled by i386, I will get error in 64-bit installation.

I was wondering is there any way that I can specify using dll from x64 to build a package works for 64 bit machine and dll from i386 to build one for 32 bit machine. Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. I want to use 64 bit R because I am running out of memory in 32 bit R, but I am forced to use the latter to link my Fortran DLL

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but just in case people have the same issue. It's a designed issue and the 32-bit and 64-bit compiled files need to be built separately. Solution is that to build 64 bit version, i386 needs to be moved out of the folder.